# encrypting a remote VPS, and letting it boot without entering a password

Tags: disk-encryption, vps, password-store

I Have rented a VPS and I want to encrypt it's data, at least on the /home directory, because I don't want the owners of the VPS to have a look at the content of my data.
But the server **already has data** on it.

my questions are:
1- /home isn't a separate partition, neither /boot .. in this case can I encrypt it?
2- How would the server boot, it's running headless, and I don't have access to it.
3- I have a trusted server on my home, can I use it somehow to hold the password so the VPS server would access it and get the password hash and boot?

Thanks a lot, have a nice day.

Comment: The VPS host can look at the data anyway. For example they can grab the keys from ram-dump which is easy to do for virtual machines. Only way to avoid that is to use the server as storage for encrypted data, without telling it the keys at all. But then it won't function as a normal server...

Comment: yeah, I figured they'd see it anyway.
That's unfortunate.